# What exactly is sol/s as far as a hash rate is concerned?

Tags: hashpower, terminology

What is sol/s? Is it the same as MH/s? Please don't answer it depends, because that makes no sense!

I have already tried googling this question but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It means "solutions per second" and means the number of attempts per second made at generating a valid block.

In Bitcoin, where 1 hash is equivalent to 1 attempt at a potential valid block, it's equivalent to "hashes per second".